# Proplem When I try to publish my website

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to publish my website on a [webhost](http://www.parallels.com/)  which using plesk panel but when I upload my publushed website I keep getting this error :

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a 
connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify 
that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured 
to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)


Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
```

Can any one give me a solution for this ?!
Thanks

**UPDATE**
my connection string

```
        conn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" 
    + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~\App_Data\learn.mdf") 
    + ";Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the connection string in your `web.config` is set to the hosted SQL Server instance, or to the correct SQL Server.

Comment: I am using a connection string in .cs file instead ! and it works fine locally

Comment: @Israa Abd - If the connection string points to a local SQL Server, it is very likely that the hosted site doesn't have access to it.

Comment: @Oded - this is my connection string(I'll update the question) : 
        conn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" 
        + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~\App_Data\learn.mdf") 
        + ";Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";

Comment: @Israa Abd - So, two questions. Do you deploy the data file? Does the hosting company allow this (that is, is SQL Express installed on the hosted computer)?

Comment: @Oded - Yes I'm deploying the whole site , and how to know if my hosting supports this . I know that the SQL server is supported .

Comment: @Israa Abd - ensure that the _instance name_ is correct. You are using `.\SQLEXPRESS`, your host might have a different one.

Comment: @Oded - then I should change the Data Source which it is a .NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server. but I can't find any of these in host ther is : Databases option which contains MySQL only . and ODBC DSN settings which contains SQLServer and others .

Comment: @Israa - You will have to ask your network admins/hosting company.